# JSON parse auto sort number object keys problem

Tags: javascript, json, jsonparser

I have a interesting problem. I am working on an object which returns from my webapi in json format.

JSON Object

```
{"3852":20.0,"2852":20.0,"1852":59.0}
```

Above code is my original json code. It is auto-sorted when I run the code below on it, however:

```
JSON.parse('{"3852":20.0,"2852":20.0,"1852":59.0}')
```

I don't want it to be sorted when I run the json.parse function.

Comment: Numeric keys in javascript objects get sorted by default. There is no  guaranteed order in objects. Use array if you need order